# How are interplanetary spacecraft protected from biological contamination while being integrated on their launchers?

Tags: fairings, forward-contamination, planetary-protection, launcher-integration

After having been disinfected in some NASA lab for forward planetary protection reasons, how are spacecraft stored and brought to the launch pad and loaded into the fairings, in order to prevent them from being re-contaminated? How isolated from their environment, like the hot humid tropic air of Florida and Guyana, are the fairings? Are special fairings used for space missions where forward biological contamination is of importance?